# How to use classic ASP to format TIME into HH:MM AM/PM format?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I am going nuts with this one. I have a mySQL table with a field of TIME type. I want to display a time such as 09:00 PM, and not 09:00:00 PM. I got this to work but think there must be a better way -

monday = FormatDateTime(rs("d1s"), vbLongTime)
response.write replace(monday,":00 AM"," AM")

I've read through a lot of resources but can't put my finger on how best to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, if there is a way to eliminate the first digit if a 0, such as not 09:00 AM but 9:00 AM

Answer (score 2):

since you are using MySQL, use **[`DATE_FORMAT`](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)** in your `SELECT` statement,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ColumnName, '%l:%i %p')
```

## [See SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2493)

Comment: Hi John, that worked great, thanks so much. I need to brush up on my mySQL for sure. Question though, as there are 14 fields, would my select statement need to have 14 of those columnName requests, one for each day's open and closing time??? Again thank you!

Comment: @user1694768 definitely, yes :D

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.